# Sheva Brachos for zivug sheini

Tags: wedding, sheva-brachos, zivug-sheini

I know it says in Shulchan Aruch that, in a case where both spouses are getting married for the second time, all sheva brachos are recited under the chuppah and then after the meal on the first day only. However I've heard that a second marriage has "3 days of simcha (joy)". During this three-day period, I've heard, the bracha of "asher bara" (the last of the sheva brachos) may be said. Is this true? What is the source for this? Must there be panim chadoshos (people present who are new to the celebration) in such a case, as there must be for sheva brachos for seven days after a first marriage? What about if it's Shabbos, when we normally don't need panim chadoshos for sheva brachos for a first marriage: is the same true for saying "asher bara" for a second marriage?

A separate question, what other significance is there for the 3 days of simcha for a second marriage?

Comment: For the second question, there's no _Tachanun_.

Comment: "Must there be panim chadoshos...as there must be for sheva brachos for seven days after a first marriage?" Where did you come up with that rule from? There is never a need for panim chadoshos to say "asher bara" during any of the seven days after a first marriage.

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe not Panim Chadoshos but some say you need someone else to be there by the seudah outside of the family (someone "chashuv") in order to say Asher Bara when there is no minyan

Comment: @Yehoshua It's the Rama in 62:7 and you just need someone else around so the meal will be _likhvod_ the wedding, not just your regular family meals.

Answer (score 1):

Whether Asher Bara may be said at meals during the three days seems to be a dispute between the [Tur](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7291) and the [Shulchan Aruch](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7687). The Beit Shemuel ([EH 62 sk 14](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7689)) rules to say it while the Aruch HaShulchan ([62:42](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14243&st=&pgnum=367)) rules not to. All agree that the special wedding Zimmun is to be used ([Shulchan Aruch EH 62:13](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7689)).

A Minyan and Panim Chadashot are never required for Asher Bara for a first marriage ([:4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7687)) and I don't see why this case should be any different.

The obligation to have days of Simcha is just like the obligation following a first marriage (except in duration) and is detailed in [Shulchan Aruch EH 64:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7690):

> צריך לשמוח עמה...שלא יעשה מלאכה ולא ישא ויתן בשוק אלא אוכל ושותה ושמח עמה...הגה: וחתן אסור בעשיית מלאכה ואסור לצאת יחידי לשוק.‏
>   He must be happy with her...he shouldn't do work or do business in the market, but he eats, drinks and is happy with her... GLOSS: A groom is forbidden to do work and is forbidden to go out to the market alone.

In other words: relax and have a nice time together.

Comment: Should they wear Shabbos clothes for all 3 days as well? Definitely not a "chiyuv" but is there an inyun still?

Comment: It's the same as the 7 days after first marriage. What's an "inyun"?

Comment: "Yeshivish" for if there is a "reason" for doing something even though it might not be obligatory or even a strong minhag